# Plotting multiple survival curves on the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I have the prediction scores for 6 different machine learning models. I also have the survival time and the survival status (death or censored) for each sample. I've ordered the scores for each model from highest to lowest, and assigned the samples above (or equal) to the median as group 1, and the samples below the median as group 0.

the samples that belog to group 1 are combined together into one data frame called `ones`, the same for the samples that belong to group 0, combined together to `zeros` df.

Now I want to plot survival curves for all the models together, one plot for group 1 and one plot for group 0. So both plots, would ave 6 different curves, each curve belongs to the prediction scores of a model. The purpose is to see the difference between the different models. So a plot for the "one" group and a plot to the "zero" group.

This is a small subset of the combined group 1 data frame (group 0 looks pretty similar):

```
> dput(ones[1:10,])
structure(list(rowname = c("107T", "115T", "278T", "324T", "333T", 
"356T", "35T", "383T", "391T", "Choueiri_CCR_2016_p021_ar_301"
), survival_time_model1 = c(33, 36, NA, 14, 27, 21, 26, 11, 18, 
NA), survival_status_model1 = c(1, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, NA), 
    prediction_scores_model1 = c(0.495171628824114, 0.494213199887482, 
    NA, 0.495106945330192, 0.493049679663768, 0.49476988798987, 
    0.496043623723607, 0.497109298739248, 0.49675341019738, NA
    ), above_below_median_model1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    survival_time_ciber = c(33, NA, 24, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11, 18, 
    NA), survival_status_model2 = c(1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1, 1, NA), prediction_scores_model2 = c(0.494963177939037, 
    NA, 0.49464555338203, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.49136567260834, 0.50374015633869, 
    NA), above_below_median_model2 = structure(c(2L, NA, 2L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    survival_time_model3X = c(33, 36, NA, 14, NA, 21, 26, 11, 
    18, NA), survival_status_model3X = c(1, 0, NA, 1, NA, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, NA), prediction_scores_model3X = c(0.425424508230426, 
    0.535192595397441, NA, 0.500781949599446, NA, 0.4442485884797, 
    0.512112667034256, 0.462703580888635, 0.547199951953444, 
    NA), above_below_median_model3X = structure(c(2L, 2L, NA, 
    2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    survival_time_model4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 14, NA, 21, 26, 11, 18, 
    NA), survival_status_model4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, NA), prediction_scores_model4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.518055395775532, 
    NA, 0.470577659621084, 0.54309987130442, 0.54309987130442, 
    0.594326057020244, NA), above_below_median_model4 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    survival_time_model5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    18, 11), survival_status_model5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1, 0), prediction_scores_model5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.403121325191364, 0.390988406954276), above_below_median_model5 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    survival_time_baseline = c(33, 36, 24, 14, 27, NA, 26, NA, 
    NA, NA), survival_status_baseline = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, NA, 
    0, NA, NA, NA), prediction_scores_baseline = c(0.427234634852229, 
    0.427234622159368, 0.427234632944309, 0.396701373192848, 
    0.427234631384541, NA, 0.427234618146735, NA, NA, NA), rank_baseline = c(170, 
    161, 169, 144, 168, NA, 159, NA, NA, NA), above_below_median_baseline = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Yes there are alot of NA but it's ok, it's just because of the samples splitting and the grouping process.

So now, I use `survfit` for each model alone:

```
fit_model1 = survfit(Surv(survival_time_model1, survival_status_model1) ~ 1, data = ones)
fit_model2 = survfit(Surv(survival_time_model2, survival_status_model2) ~ 1, data = ones)
fit_model3X = survfit(Surv(survival_time_model3X, survival_status_model3X) ~ 1, data = ones)
fit_model4 = survfit(Surv(survival_time_model4, survival_status_model4) ~ 1, data = ones)
fit_model5 = survfit(Surv(survival_time_model5, survival_status_model5) ~ 1, data = ones)
fit_baseline = survfit(Surv(survival_time_baseline, survival_status_baseline) ~ 1, data = ones)
```

And I get each seprate plot into the plots list:

```
fit_list = list(Model1= fit_model1, 
                 Model2 = fit_model2, 
                 Model3X = fit_model3X, 
                 Model4 = fit_model4, 
                 Model5 = fit_model5, 
                 Baseline = fit_baseline)

colors = c('palevioletred1', 'salmon3', 'tomato2' ,'seagreen4', 'slateblue', 'turquoise3' )
plots = list()

for (i in 1:length(fit_list)){
  plots[[i]] = ggsurvplot(fit_list[[i]], data = ones, conf.int = FALSE, 
                          legend.title = "Models", 
                          pval = FALSE, risk.table = FALSE,
                          ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
                          linetype = "solid", color = colors[[i]])
}
```

So I have the curves inside `plots`, so `plots[[1]]` is the first curve, `plots[[2]]` is the second and so on, but I want all of those curves to be on the same graph with different colors and with labels (to know which model is which). This is where I'm having trouble. How do I do that ?

I was able to do this with a classic ggplot2 approach but the curves are very smooth without the vertical little lines, so it doesn't work.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer on your former question [Plotting survival curves from two different models on the same graph, in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76783810/plotting-survival-curves-from-two-different-models-on-the-same-graph-in-r/76783858#76783858)?

Comment: @stefan I totally forgot about it. It works perfectly, thank you and sorry for the unnecessary question.

Comment: Haha. I sometimes forget about my answers and re-invent the wheel. :D Will close that one as a duplicate.